# InstalledAppFlow run_local_server hangs when offline

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am using `InstalledAppFlow` for an application like so

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secret, scopes=SCOPES)

flow.run_local_server()
```

But the problem that I have is that if my application is offline (as it will be at times) then `flow.run_local_server()` just hangs forever. The webpage errors out, but `flow.run_local_server()` never returns or throws an error. When my application is offline it just needs to skip this and move on, but I can't find any way to cause this to timeout, throw an error, or return. Is there a kwarg I need to pass to this or another way to authenticate that will let me control this?

Comment: Its going to hang its trying to connect to the internet.  Catch the error.

Comment: The problem is that it hangs forever and never raises and error or returns so I can't just catch the error.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick summary of the authentication process as I understand it.

1. First the user is directed to the GCP authorization page where they actually login.
2. After logging in here they are redirected to the local server set up by `flow.run_local_server()`. This is how the credentials is actually passed to the application without requiring the user to copy-paste.
3. After the user is redirected to the local server the credentials are passed, the local server closes and the rest of the application can resume.

The problem with being offline is that the user can't access the GCP page so they are never redirected to the local page either. Because of this the local server never received a request so it doesn't close which means that it will continue to wait for that request forever.

My solution, which admittedly feels rather hacky, is to move `flow.run_local_server()` to a separate thread. This still won't close the local server so it will continue to hang, but after `thread.join(TIMEOUT)` make a request to the local server so that it gets its request and closes (erroring in the process, but we can catch and handle that).

```
from threading import Thread
import requests
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

host = 'localhost'
port = 8080

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets(client_secret, scopes=SCOPES)

def run_local_server():
    try:
        flow.run_local_server(host, port)
    except Exception:
        pass  # Just ignore any errors

thread = Thread(target=run_local_server)
thread.start()
thread.join(90)
if thread.is_alive():
    requests.get(f'http://{host}:{port}/')
```

Note that we still need to handle errors when trying to access `flow.credentials` because those won't be populated if we manually killed the local server, but at least that is an error that can be caught and handled.
The other consideration here is that with `thread.join(TIMEOUT)` that means that the user now only has `TIMEOUT` seconds to sign in, but typically this process should only take a few seconds so setting this to like 90 seconds should probably be adequate, but certainly worth being aware of.